# Rewrite subdirectory to index.html

Tags: .htaccess

I have a subdirectory setup with a static website inside.

But when I go to www.site.com/directory/ it doesn't show the index page, only www.site.com/directory/index.html works.

Is there a way for .htaccess to rewrite this?

I can't just forward all urls because there are also other pages like www.site.com/directory/other.html that still need to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `/directory/` it's enough that you put an .htaccess file with the directive:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

If it still does not work, maybe there are other server directives conflicting with it.

Answer (score 1):

In Apache config you should enable `AllowOverride` so you could set different options in `.htaccess`. In that file you could set the `DirectoryIndex` directive.

See:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride